# urxvt - force column width

Tags: terminal, urxvt, tiling-wm

I'm using urxvt with a tiling window manager (awesome) and would like to have my terminals maintain 80 columns irrespective of the window's size.

So I was wondering if there is a way to force urxvt to resize the font/spacing in order to maintain a certain column width?

Spawning terminals with `urxvtc -g 80` does not do the trick. 
I've looked at `man 7 urxvt` with no luck...

Comment: In case it's revelant, which window manager?

Comment: I'm assuming `urxvt` requests a certain window size based on your default font size, and your tiling WM ignores it.

Comment: @Mikel I'm using awesome wm and I definitely agree that's what's going on, I'm just wondering if there's a way to make urxvt scale my font to fit a certain character length/width.

Comment: Did you try running `stty columns 80`?

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be two questions:

- how to start `urxvt`, making it automatically select an appropriate fontsize provided that `urxvt` uses 80 columns, **and**
- how to keep `urxvt` using 80 columns (and automatically adjusting the fontsize) as one resizes its window.

X applications may *ask* for a given window size, but the window manager *tells* the application which size it will use.  Terminal emulators usually ask for window sizes which are multiples (rows) of the font height, and (columns) of the font width.  Doing that makes it possible for the window manager to cooperate (a little...) when resizing the window, as well as providing visual feedback for the *rows*-and-*columns* layout.

When `urxvt` is using a TrueType font, it can (in principle) use any scaled size.  When it opens a font, it obtains the height and width of a character cell from that.  You *could* use the same values along with the screensize and compute an appropriate scale to ask for, to keep the window no wider than 80 columns.

But the hard part is that if the window manager disagrees, it will change that request, possibly changing both the window's height and width. Either dimension could be increased or decreased independently of the other.  In a tiling window manager, you cannot even assume that the window is allowed to shrink to maintain a suitable aspect ratio.  The end result is that `urxvt` gets a window size, and then has to decide how to chop it up into character cells.

The window manager's initial layout changes are usually detected by the terminal emulator, which passes this on to the (possibly not yet started) shell as a window size change event **`SIGWINCH`**.

Likewise, window resizing after startup is passed on as **`SIGWINCH`**.

Given that, you *could* write an application in the shell which catches **`SIGWINCH`** and modifies the font size used by `urxvt` (which may then ask the window manager for a better layout).

This is *doable*, but out-of-the-box, `urxvt` provides no direct way to do it.  It would require some scripting/programming:

- `urxvt` (since 2.6 dated 2004/4/2) implements a control sequence adapted from [xterm #94 in 1999/3/27](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_94):

> extend dynamic colors control sequences to allow users to determine the colors and font which are currently active.

which refers to this feature documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

> If a **"?"** is given rather than a name or RGB specification,
>   xterm replies with a control sequence of the same form which
>   can be used to set the corresponding dynamic color.  Because
>   more than one pair of color number and specification can be
>   given in one control sequence, xterm can make more than one
>   reply.

and

> ```
>        Ps = 5 0  -> Set Font to Pt.
> ```

So an application could do

```
printf '\033]50;?\007'
```

and get back the current font — up to 250 characters, at any rate (see [the source code](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/command.C#L3562))

- after making suitable calculations, your application could update the font (same control sequence).

Oddly, in a quick check the copy of `urxvt` (Debian 7) does not **work** for the [test-script in `xterm`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/query-fonts.pl) for the feature.  But if the feature could be made to work for you, that's the means by which you could implement automatic font rescaling.